# Count number automatically for card view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

I am trying to make a method that if the card `position == 0` then `viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText("1");`" and if `position == 1` then `viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText("2");` but the problem that I want to number all cards automatically because these method contents the position 0,1 only so I need a method to number all cards by position automatically.

Here's my activity method:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
            Getting_Posts.class, R.layout.post_card_design, PostViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Getting_Posts model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setProfile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getProfile());
            viewHolder.setDescribe(model.getDescribe());
            viewHolder.setWallpaper(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getWallpaper());

            //heres my methods but its for 3 cards only
            if (position==0){viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText("1");}
            if (position==1){viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText("2");}
            if (position==2){viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText("3");}
        }

    };

    mPostList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);}
```

Comment: Sort Items using FirebaseRecycler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249524/sorting-items-position-using-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: So the value is position + 1? Seems like a for loop would handle that.

Comment: Can you give me completely solve please

Comment: Alexander, I need to put string instead of putting in firebase

Comment: just use .setText(String.valueOf(position+1));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position` will always be one less than the actual number, because the index always starts at 0. Just use `position + 1`each time you call `viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText("");`.

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
        Getting_Posts.class, R.layout.post_card_design, PostViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Getting_Posts model, int position) {

        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
        viewHolder.setProfile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getProfile());
        viewHolder.setDescribe(model.getDescribe());
        viewHolder.setWallpaper(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getWallpaper());

        viewHolder.mPostSortNum.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

    }

};

mPostList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);}
```

Comment: this didn't solve it, the app crashed ... and it gives the following issue "at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)"

Comment: That's because you have to first convert it to a String type and then print it!